# compute the discrete(sampled) time process noise matrix

Tags: probability-theory

Given continuous time state transition equation as follows, 
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=Ax+\nu
$$
where $\nu \sim N(\mathbf{0},Q)$, $Q$ being the process noise matrix, one can compute the discrete(sampled) time process noise matrix as follow,
$$
Q(\delta t)=\int\limits_{0}^{\delta t}{{{e}^{A\tau }}Q{{e}^{{{A}^{T}}\tau }}d\tau }
$$

I want to ask why.

Comment: where did you get this from?

Comment: actually here, page47, http://www.cs.unc.edu/~tracker/media/pdf/SIGGRAPH2001_Slides_08.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed this is used often in electrical engineering such as design of Kalman filters, if I recall correctly.

$$\mathbf Q(k)=\int\limits_{k\,T}^{(k+1)\,T}{{\mathbf \phi((k+1)T,\tau)\;}\mathbf Q(\tau){\;\mathbf \phi((k-1)T,\tau)}^\top d\tau }$$

gives the definition of *the discrete-time noise covariance* (usually defined for a certain time interval) it follows the mathematical definition of *covariance* and *autocorrelation*. Herein $\mathbf Q(t)$ is the *continuous time process noise covariance matrix*. The integral can be also approximated by a sum.

In your notation, $\delta t$ corresponds to the piece of time interval $[kT,(k+1)T]$. Further, $\phi$ shall represent the *variable of state* or, better said, through your first equation determine *the state transition*. In your case this is the solution of your first differential equation (noise excluded of course) detemining state transitions following $\phi(t)\sim x(t)=\exp(\mathbf A t)$, hence:

$$\mathbf \phi(\tau)=\exp(\mathbf A \tau)$$
$$\mathbf \phi^\top(\tau)=\exp(\mathbf A^\top \tau)$$

where ${}^\top$ indicates transposition, all capital bold symbols are matrices and $\phi$ is a vector.

Once you apply the above integral to your case, you will see that the matrix $\mathbf Q$ acts with its elements operating as autocorrelation of the continuous process noise on the variable of state — these are commonly denoted $\sigma_{ij}$ — where $i,j$ are some indices.